# serialization limit and executed transactions are lost

Tags: transactions

I get a lot of "serialization time limit 15000us exceeded" when sending transactions to the EOS mainnet with eosjs. Also, a lot of the transactions return status = executed, but are not found on the blockchain when I use dFuse to check transactions.

Do other have the same problem? Or can someone explain why?

Answer (score 1):

This is a setting from nodeos.

```
nodeos -h ...
  --abi-serializer-max-time-ms arg (=15)
                                        Override default maximum ABI 
                                        serialization time allowed in ms
```

This is set to 15 milliseconds by default.

As for your dfuse question, I would highly recommend asking them directly in their Telegram: https://t.me/dfuseAPI

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the training and came across the same when creating accounts.

```
cleos create account eosio bob EOS6RvnAH2Qnb3QdJS7apG8b9YjD346U8NzVfCW2y7SNM2izGUVF8
```

> Error 3015010: ABI serialization time has exceeded the deadline Error
> Details: serialization time limit 15000us exceeded Failed to
> deserialize variant Invalid transaction*

Thanks to Nat for answer but please indicate how to override the 15 ms.